# Can a Git repo with a deleted blob file be repaired

Tags: git, version-control

I deleted a blob file from within my `.git/objects/xx` folder resulting in dangling commits and blobs. The blob file isn't in my recycle bin and i don't have another repo I can clone a copy from. I don't think i'll be able to retrieve that blob file so am I gonna be forced to unitialize an re-initialize my git repo so i can push my files or can i modify some previous commits to mitigate this problem?